# Passing PHP variable to SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userlogin"]);

    mysql_connect("uritomyhost","myusername","password"); 
    mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
    mysql_query('UPDATE table SET field = field + ($userlogin)');
```

Is this the right way of getting userlogin from the post request and then inserting it to my SQL query?

Comment: What point is it using a + with a database field with a user supplied value?

Answer (score 5):

Stop using outdated functions and use PDO instead.

```
$stmt = PDO::prepare('UPDATE table SET field = field + :field');
$stmt->execute(array('field' => $_POST["userlogin"]));
```

Read some [information about PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
In short: it escapes your data for you, is quite consistent across databases and generally just easier.

Comment: How should I connect to it? This only get ths value and insert it. How do I log in to my database with this code?

Comment: You'd use the [__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php). See the examples on that page :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` after mysql connection and
Use double quotes

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = field + ({$userlogin})");
```

Comment: To add on this, when using single quotes, [variables do not expand](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) ***Edit***: And it also seems like you call your variable `$user` instead of `$userlogin`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql_real_scape_string() just after connecting to database ...
so change your code to this :

```
mysql_connect("uritomyhost","myusername","password"); 
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
$userlogin = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userlogin"]);
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = '$userlogin'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userlogin"]);

mysql_connect("uritomyhost","myusername","password"); 
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = value where user='$user'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_query` for you queries(notice the **i**) and use prepared statements. Using prepared statements is more secure than using straight queries and including the variable in the query string. Moreover, mysql will be deprecated soon.  Example :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$city = "Amersfoort";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($district);

/* fetch value */
$stmt->fetch();

printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Mysqli is not more secure when being used this way. Mysqli is **only** more secure when using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), just like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: yeah, sorry forgot to mention that, editing my answer. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = field + ('$user')");
```

However,

You might be updating all the fields in your table because you have no where in your `UPDATE` clause

Shouldn't it rather be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = field WHERE user= '$user'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to `INSERT` instead of using `Update`. Why `field = field + ($userlogin)`? This will concatenate the values. And one more thing please use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tanlename (field) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $user);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: It's supposed to count with the current value?